# Cannot modify an area being edited in a dedicated buffer

Tags: org-mode

When I use <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> (`org-edit-special`) to edit an `org-mode` code block, I am running into an error. After I open the code block and edit it, then exit with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> again, the code block is locked (I think that is the right term).

If I try to edit the same area in the `org` file in either `org-mode` or in the `org-edit-special` `emacs-lisp-mode` I get the following error (as displayed in my `**Messages**` buffer):

> user-error: Cannot modify an area being edited in a dedicated buffer

even though I have closed the `org-mode src` `emacs-lisp-mode` editing buffer with either <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd>

I am using the following version of Emacs:

> GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of
>   2018-06-06

with the following version of org-mode:

> Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @
>   /app/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/org/)

installed on Ubuntu 18.04 with [Flatpak via Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnu.emacs)

**Here are some screenshots if that might relevant to others:**

Here is a screenshot of me before editing with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>:
[image: Here is a screenshot of me before editing with <kbd>C-c '</kbd>]

Here is a screenshot of me editing:
[image: Here is a screenshot of me editing]

Here is a screenshot of that part of the file now being locked:
[image: Here is a screenshot of that part of the file now being locked]

I am quite sure this a problem is due to a plugin, and not a problem caused by Emacs or Org-mode, but I wanted to post this in case anyone else was running into the same issue. What really motivated me to create this post was the fact that there are [only 30 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Cannot%20modify%20an%20area%20being%20edited%20in%20a%20dedicated%20buffer%22) for searching for this error on Google (hopefully soon to be 8).

Answer (score 3):

It turns out it I was correct in my suspicion that this was not due to `Emacs` or `Org-mode`, but in fact was due to my `paredit` configuration:

`(use-package paredit
  :ensure t
  :config
  (autoload 'enable-paredit-mode "paredit" "Turn on pseudo-structural editing of Lisp code." t)
  ;; (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook                       #'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook                    #'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'eval-expression-minibuffer-setup-hook   #'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'ielm-mode-hook                          #'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook                          #'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook              #'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook                        #'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'geiser-repl-mode-hook                   #'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook                    #'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook                       #'enable paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'clojurescript-mode-hook                 #'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'org-src-mode-hook                       #'enable paredit-mode))`

specifically, it seems that:

`(add-hook 'org-src-mode-hook                       #'enable paredit-mode)`

was causing my issue. If you are having the error

> Cannot modify an area being edited in a dedicated buffer

and have this line enabled in your `paredit` configuration, I recommend commenting it out and seeing if that fixes your issue.

Comment: How did you come up with that conclusion? I'm having the same message error but in my case I don't even have `paredit` installed, could you share how did you find out the culprit?

Comment: If it helps someone - the "dedicated buffer" in this context (org-mode) is actually the `C-'` which is the temp buffer that opens up so you can write out some language specific code that you must have in your org file. 

If you're like me, what happened was that you opened this buffer (fat-fingered C-') and its still open. Find it, destroy it! :D